# Access VBA - create Textbox formula check (check last digit)

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have to create some Number field-check of entered values in Textbox with formula in VBA, but don't know how to even start. Here is example:

Textbox field value - 132549

1. you exclude 6, so you use 13254
2. then you do product and sum with other numbers like:
   4*2 + 5*3 + 2*3 + 3*4 + 1*5 = 46
3. then you do 46 mod 11 = 2
4. then 11 minus 2 = 9 and result here must match last digit (in this example last digit is correct)

I'm an intermediate VBA programmer, but this is over my head. Any advice much appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved It on my own - I know this looks a bit childish, but It works as It should.

```
  Sub test()

        Dim Seven As Integer
        Dim Six As Integer
        Dim Five As Integer
        Dim Four As Integer
        Dim Three As Integer
        Dim Two As Integer
        Dim One As Integer

        Dim Seven_Sum As Integer
        Dim Six_Sum As Integer
        Dim Five_Sum As Integer
        Dim Four_Sum As Integer
        Dim Three_Sum As Integer
        Dim Two_Sum As Integer
        Dim One_Sum As Integer

        Dim All_Sum As Integer
        Dim Do_Modulus As Integer
        Dim Check_Digit As Integer

        Seven = Mid(Text0, 7, 1)
        Seven_Sum = Seven * 2

        Six = Mid(Text0, 6, 1)
        Six_Sum = Six * 3

        Five = Mid(Text0, 5, 1)
        Five_Sum = Five * 4

        Four = Mid(Text0, 4, 1)
        Four_Sum = Four * 5

        Three = Mid(Text0, 3, 1)
        Three_Sum = Three * 6

        Two = Mid(Text0, 2, 1)
        Two_Sum = Two * 7

        One = Mid(Text0, 1, 1)
        One_Sum = One * 8

        All_Sum = Seven_Sum + Six_Sum + Five_Sum + Four_Sum + Three_Sum + Two_Sum + One_Sum

        Do_Modulus = All_Sum Mod 11
        Check_Digit = 11 - Do_Modulus

'Finally check for correct serial number validation based on last digit in Textbox
        If Mid(Text0, 8, 1) <> Check_Digit Then

        MsgBox "This serial number is faulty. Last digit of this entered serial number should be :" & Check_Digit
        End If

        End Sub
```

Comment: Maciej Los code is much more versatile and maintainable. you should adopt and study it both for your current project and to enhance your VBA skills

Comment: @user3598756, thanks for response. And that's what I'm planning to do, after I finish project, because I'm in a hurry to finish It now. I'll probably include It in my project, but a little bit later - when I test It.

Comment: If you're in hurry, why don't you use my "lazy-programmer" implementation? Please, read my answer carefully. There's many useful information how to use `IsValidNymber` function.

Answer (score 2):

You have to write custom function which will take a number as input parameter and return boolean value (true/false). A "lazy-programmer" implementation may look like:

```
Public Function IsValidNumber(ByVal iNum As Long) As Boolean
Dim consums As String, digits As String
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

'control sums
consums = "23345"
'convert number to its string representation and reject last digit
digits = Left(CStr(iNum), 5)
'reverse string
digits = StrReverse(digits)
'loop through the chars in string
For i = 1 To Len(digits)
    'convert single char to digit and calculate sum
    j = j + CInt(Mid(digits, i, 1)) * CInt(Mid(consums, i, 1))
Next
'get modulo
i = j Mod 11
'deduct the result of modulo from constant
j = 11 - i

'return
IsValidNumber = (j = CInt(Right(CStr(iNum), 1)))

End Function
```

How to call it? Create a procedure as below:

```
Sub Test()
Dim i As Long

i = 132549

MsgBox IsValidNumber(i)

End Sub
```

Run it (`F5`) and check what happens.

Note: you have to add new module to be able to paste above code into it.

See below "visual representation" of `for...next` loop steps.

```
|==================================================|
| Iteration | Control number | Current digit | Sum |
| (step)    |  (multiplier)  |(reverse order)|     |
|==================================================|
|     1     |        2       |       4       |   8 |
|     2     |        3       |       5       |  15 |
|     3     |        3       |       2       |   6 |
|     4     |        4       |       3       |  12 |
|     5     |        5       |       1       |   5 |
|==================================================|
```

Comment: thanks for provided code, but I'm not sure how to use It with my needs. I posted my answer, this is what I wanted.

Comment: Thank you, @user3598756. Non-lazy version have to work on arrays of integers.

Comment: @LuckyLuke82, Let me know if it was helpful to you.

Comment: Yes, It was, thanks. But I used Gustav suggestion, It better suits my needs.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm asking about VBA code for formula above, I know how to use Access
>   and VBA coding. What I need is someone to tell me how I have to
>   extract each number from textbox, multiply them and SUM these results.
>   Then use Mod function, and so on, as explained in question.

As i understand the main problem is to get numbers from text.
I think you can use next logic (it shows idea only).

```
Dim nLen as Integer    
Dim stInput as string

stInput = nz(Me.Field)
nLen = Len(stInput)

Dim arrNumbers(nLen) As Integer
Dim nIndex asInteger
dim nValue as Intger

For nIndex = 0 to nLen
    nValue = Mid(stInput, nIndex, 1)
    arrNumbers(nIndex) = nValue
Next nIndex

'-- you can use arrNumbers to get access to your numbers
```

Comment: I'm asking about VBA code for formula above, I know how to use Access and VBA coding. What I need is someone to tell me how I have to extract each number from textbox, multiply them and SUM these results. Then use Mod function, and so on, as explained in question.

Comment: I will change my answer.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know how to use your code in my case.

Comment: I'm confused a bit. Can you clarify your expectations? What questions do you have?

Answer (score 1):

What you ask for is probably a Modulus-11 check. You also can have a Modulus-10 check, and both can be combined in one function:

```
Public Function ModulusCheck(ByVal strNum As String, ByVal intModulus As Integer) As Integer

  ' Checks that strNum is a Modulus-10 or -11 number with
  ' a valid check digit.
  ' Non-numeric characters are ignored.

  ' Maximum length of number.
  Const cintNumLenMax = 32

  Dim strChk    As String
  Dim strTmp    As String
  Dim strVal    As String
  Dim intChr    As Integer
  Dim intLen    As Integer
  Dim intSum    As Integer
  Dim intVal    As Integer
  Dim intWeight As Integer
  Dim intCount  As Integer
  Dim intChk    As Integer

  Select Case intModulus
    Case 10, 11
      intLen = Len(strNum)
      If intLen > 0 Then
        ' Remove non-numeric characters.
        For intCount = 1 To intLen
          intChr = Asc(Mid(strNum, intCount))
          If intChr >= 48 And intChr <= 57 Then
            strTmp = strTmp & Chr(intChr)
          End If
        Next intCount
        strNum = strTmp
        intLen = Len(strNum)

        If intLen > 1 Then
          If intLen <= cintNumLenMax Then
            ' Separate number and check digit.
            strVal = Mid(strNum, 1, intLen - 1)
            strChk = Mid(strNum, intLen, 1)
            For intCount = 1 To intLen - 1
              intVal = Val(Mid(strVal, intLen - intCount, 1))
              Select Case intModulus
                Case 10
                  intWeight = 1 + (intCount Mod 2)
                  intVal = intWeight * intVal
                  intVal = Int(intVal / 10) + (intVal Mod 10)
                Case 11
                  intWeight = 2 + ((intCount - 1) Mod 6)
                  intVal = intWeight * intVal
              End Select
              intSum = intSum + intVal
            Next intCount
            intSum = intSum + Val(strChk)
            intChk = (intSum Mod intModulus = 0)
          End If
        End If
      End If
  End Select

  ModulusCheck = intChk

End Function
```

To check a number, the function will return True for OK. However:

```
ValidNumber = ModulusCheck("132549", 11)
```

will be False, while:

```
ValidNumber = ModulusCheck("132543", 11)
```

returns True.

So either you have some non-standard validation or you've got it wrong with 9 or 6, as the check digit for "13254" to pass a Modulus-11 check is 3.

Comment: Thanks @Gustav, I tried It. I had to change a little bit due to specific needs, but your code works fine.